# Attempting to install ASP.NET Core Template Pack 2017.3, getting an error

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core

I installed the extension and ran the command [from the link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack20173) which gives the following error:

```
dotnet : 
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet new -i "MadsKristensen.AspNetCore.Web.Templates::*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

edit: So looks like the error *might* have been a false positive, I tried creating a static webpage as per the instructions.

However when attempting to compile I get the following errors:

> error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Tools
>   from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project
>   to select a different version.  error NU1605:  HadakaAngular (>=
>   1.0.0) -> AspNetCore.StaticSiteHelper (>= 1.0.9) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1) -> System.Diagnostics.Tools (>= 4.3.0) 
>   error NU1605:  HadakaAngular (>= 1.0.0) -> AspNetCore.StaticSiteHelper
>   (>= 1.0.9) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   System.Diagnostics.Tools (>= 4.0.1) error NU1605: Detected package
>   downgrade: System.Net.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   error NU1605:  HadakaAngular (>= 1.0.0) -> AspNetCore.StaticSiteHelper
>   (>= 1.0.9) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1) -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.3.0) 
>   error NU1605:  HadakaAngular (>= 1.0.0) -> AspNetCore.StaticSiteHelper
>   (>= 1.0.9) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.0) ->
>   System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.0.11)

Comment: Have you installed the SDK? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Comment: yep, I've even built an asp.net core website for practice

Comment: So running just `dotnet` in terminal works?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Eellor works, but if you want to use .NET Core 2.0 you will need to change the version of some package references. Then edit the .csproj file so that the ItemGroup will look like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AspNetCore.StaticSiteHelper" Version="1.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Rebuilding/recompile and your project should download the correct versions of the packages.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the latest update of VS 2017 creates the web application with the target framework as .NET Core 2.0, while Kristensen's ASP.NET Core Template Pack 2017.3 (the latest version is 1.0.9 as of now) still stays at .NET Core 1.1.

The simplest solution is to change the target framework of the project to .NET Core 1.1, to be in line with the template pack's version. Go to project properties > Application > Target framework. Change it to .NET Core 1.1.

In the long run, we will need an update of the template pack or we need to drop it if we still want to stick to .NET Core 2.0.